# Things to be taken care by first time USA Visitor

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa

I dont know whether this is a right platform to ask this questions but I would like to know what things one needs to keep in mind if someone is visiting USA for the very first time for long time say a year or two and for work purpose?

Comment: I recommend editing the question to make it clear that you are asking about entering The USA to work. A tourist experience or even a student experience are completely different.

Comment: I'm going for work purpose but I would like to know what in general a person should know about USA before visiting the country

Comment: @aretxabaleta: Question updated